# GoLang http Server and client IP remote port as unique session?

Tags: javascript, go

I use the mentioned function for session identification with Go http server. I know that the address IP does not have to be unique, but the question is whether I can consider the IP:PORT (remote port) as unique for each session?

```
func GetIPsPorts(r *http.Request) string { //https://golangbyexample.com/golang-ip-address-http-request/
    s := ""
    IPAddress := r.Header.Get("X-REAL-IP")
    s += strings.TrimSpace(IPAddress)
    IPAddress = r.Header.Get("X-FORWARDED-FOR")
    p := za.IndexAt(IPAddress, ",")
    if p > 2 {
        IPAddress = za.Sub(IPAddress, 0, p)
    }
    s += strings.TrimSpace(IPAddress)
    IPAddress = r.RemoteAddr
    s += strings.TrimSpace(IPAddress)
    return s
}
```

Can I consider the string obtained in this way as unique for the given session.My question is whether it's always unique for 2 different parallel connections (from two different clients) ?

Comment: Your server is always listening on the same port for all connections, so why would that local port add any unique information? Your example only gets the possible remote IP anyway. This is why session information is usually sent as part of the request from the client, or else it only exists for the duration of the connection.

Comment: Even if you mean the remote port and not local port, that's still not a good choice. Clients routinely dis- and reconnect, but that doesn't necessarily indicate the end of the session, especially for mobile clients. Any particular reason to not use session cookies? Aside: typo in X-Forwarde*D*-For

Comment: Peter - thank you, yes.  
Clients disconnect and reconnect normally, but that doesn't necessarily mean the end of the session, especially for mobile clients - I've already solved this via Worker.js , but my question is whether it's always unique for 2 different parallel connections (from two different clients) ?

Comment: @JanTungli if you imagine clients connecting through a proxy it is quite easy to see how the same remote ip:port can be used be several sessions/clients

Comment: Filip , yes - anonymous proxy